# React key on array of children versus multiple hard-coded children

Tags: reactjs

```
const el1 = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  <span>Hello</span>,
  <span>World</span>,
)

const el2 = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  [
    <span>Hello</span>,
    <span>World</span>,
  ]
)
```

These two statements evaluate to the same result.

```
{
  "props":{
    "children":[
      {
        "type":"span",
        "key":null,
        "props":{
          "children":"Hello"
        },
      },
      {
        "type":"span",
        "key":null,
        "props":{
          "children":"World"
        },
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Why the second form will raise "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.",
but the first form do not ?

## Update #1: Thanks Dennis Vash inspired me.

I did this experiment.
When I toggle something in this hard-coded form,

```
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  {error ? <span>error</span> : null}
  <span>World</span>
  {error ? <span>error</span> : <a>error</a>}
  <span>!</span>
</div>
```

even something is removed from the DOM, even tag is changed. React still can sync with the DOM in minimial update.
In this hard-coded form, each individual children will be placed in the final children array in the same order. No matter how the state change, it is impossible to produce children array in different length or different order.

In the array form of children, if I toggle between these two array,

```
[
  <span>Hello</span>,
  <a>error</a>,
  <span>World</span>,
  <span>error</span>,
  <span>!</span>,
]
[
  <span>Hello</span>,
  <span>World</span>,
  <span>!</span>,
[
```

React cannot sync with the DOM in minimial update. Because the resulting children array has different length, without key, it is not possible to write a algorithm that can safely calculate the minimial DOM update and also fast enough in practical use, so it re-render anything that is uncertain.

Is that the correct reason?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The keys are clearly not unique as they are both null. 
I'm not a react expert, but why don't you use JSX instead?

Comment: Want to know why multiple hard-coded children do not need key but array of children need. Because after JSX is compiled, both form evaluate to the similar result.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the second form will raise "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.", but the first form does not?

Although the output of those examples is the same, their meaning isn't, when you group elements in an array, React can't guess their stable identity so you should [provide keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for them.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

In simple words: in this example, we know elements position within the component's tree - element `div` has two `span` sons:

```
// #1 - No Grouping
const el1 = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  <span>Hello</span>,
  <span>World</span>,
)

// JSX
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>World</span>
</div>
```

But here, in runtime, we can't guess the element's position, because usually when using an array you shuffle, filter, and aggregate the elements.

> Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.

```
// #2 Grouping
const el2 = React.createElement('div', null, [
  <span>Hello</span>,
  <span>World</span>,
])

// JSX
<div>
  [<span>Hello</span>,<span>World</span>]
</div>
```